Nodal analysis using matrices - Wrong math?
I am attempting to solve a (not so difficult) circuit using nodal analysis
However I am getting 0V for half of my nodes, which is clearly wrong, the results violate KCL
Method

I am using nodal analysis with matrices
I start with populating the    diagonal with the sum of conductances of the given node
Next I populate the "shoulders" with negatives of the sums of conductances    directly between corresponding nodes
I calculate the determinant (70)
I fill in the vector of node currents
Lastly to get the node voltage I duplicate the initial matrix, replace the    node's column with the current vector, and calculate determinant    again, which turned out to be 0 (and it shouldn't be)


Results
When calculated for all nodes, the top right half of the nodes read 0V
When used to calculate the currents, they violate KCL as currents are going into a node that has no out currents
This same approach worked on a similar, smaller circuit, and the produced results were correct.
The Question(s)
I've tried looking into the process and followed it to the best of my ability.
What am I doing wrong?
Is it something obvious?
Did I skip a step?
Edit & Answers
I have calculated the determinants wrong. Once I've done that correctly, the results were correct.
As pointed out by another user who has been of great help beyond this issue, I've come to find out that Rule of Sarrus only applies to 3x3 matrices.

@All - Although well-intentioned, the long comment chain has exceeded what is reasonable for comments. Therefore comments so far have been moved to chat & should be continued there (see link in the comment below). || As this bulk moving of comments to chat can only be done once per question, any further comments posted here may be deleted without notice. Keep it in chat now, please! || Any improvement / clarification to the question decided during the chat, should be made via an [edit], not as a comment. When someone has enough information to post an answer, please answer it as usual. TY

Comments have been moved to this chatroom and discussion should be continued there. Please do not continue the discussion in comments here.
